# what does a string in java mean in cpp?

Tags: java, c++

I am really used to java programing now I want to use cpp and I was wondering what is a string called in cpp pretty silly question ? i am trying to use int but the compiler seems not to understand

Comment: I don't seem to understand too. Are You trying to use int instead of string?

Comment: Can you please show the code you are trying to use?

Answer (score 6):

In C++ a String is called `string` or preferably `std::string` and an `int` is called `int`.  You wouldn't use an `int` instead of a `string`.

You appears to have two questions, one about string and another about int, which is confusing, but most likely you have a compilation error in your code which appears to be complaining about `int` when this is not the problem.  I suggest you post a simple example of your code so we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: You want `std::string` ;) Don't go teaching people `using namespace std`.

Answer (score 1):

The following types can be used as "strings" in C++:

1) std::string (defined in <string>)

```
#include <string>

std::string s = "hello world";
```

2) array of char

```
char s[16] = "hello";
char s[] = "world";
```

3) pointer to char (may actually point to an array)

```
const char* const globalConstString = "hello world";

void functionThatChangesString(char* s)
{
    s[0] = '!';
}
```

Note that C-style char arrays and char pointers are less "safe" than C++ strings and should be used with care.

Comment: please take the pointer to char initialization out, in current c++ it's deprecated, literals have an array type.

Comment: @chico, I am initializing a const pointer, and I believe that array-to-pointer conversion is perfectly legal as long as it is const-correct. I believe you are talking about conversion to char*, not to const char*?

Comment: no, even const correct, at initialization, it's deprecated. Decaying to pointer in arguments is no problem, but initialize a pointer with an string literal is.

Comment: sorry, you're correct, when you get const correctness, there's no problem.